# OpenCV CV_* functions error

Tags: c++, opencv, computer-vision

I am having a bit of annoying problem with OpenCV CV_* constants for functions.
I know OpenCV has recently got rid of the CV_ for a lot of constants, however I can not find any updated documentation. And all the documentation that exits it still shows the old constants.

For example CV_BGR2GRAY has been switched to COLOUR_BGR2GRAY.
Where Can I find the new updated documentation for these constants like
CV_AA, CV_HOUGH_GRADIENT. (before someone says their original website, I have already checked and it shows older versions).

Any links would be nice.
Many thanks for your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's OpenCV 3.0 documentation:
http://docs.opencv.org/trunk/index.html

Conversion constants are described here:
http://docs.opencv.org/trunk/modules/imgproc/doc/miscellaneous_transformations.html